# Многопоточный доступ к объектам

Tags: c#, .net

Допустим имеется метод обращающийся к полям класса, метод вызывается в потоках. Как я понял, поля класса являются разделяемыми между всеми потоками с этим методом, и нужно обращаться к ним с помощью примитивов синхронизации(lock’ать). А объекты создаваемые в методе не являются общими между потоками и не могут пересечься, следовательно к ним общий доступ реализовывать не нужно. Но не совсем понятно, что происходит когда к объекту создаваемому присваивается значение поля, поэтому приходится и объект локать. Собственно вопрос: что именно нужно локать в методе, а что нет. И для чего разделяемые поля часто помечают модификатором static? И не понятно почему поток может застрять внутри лока функции pop, если здесь Monitor.Enter и Exit, в конструкции Wait не используется.

```
bool TryPop(out int num){
        lock(_locker){
            return _stack.TryPop(out num);
        }
    }
    void Push(int num){
        lock(_locker){
            _stack.Push(num);
    }
}
```

Спасибо за прочтение, подскажите куда копать.

Comment: Все смешалось, люди, кони. Все ваши утверджения типа `А объекты создаваемые в методе не являются общими между потоками и не могут пересечься` и `поля класса являются разделяемыми между всеми потоками` и `что происходит когда к объекту создаваемому присваивается значение поля` - всё это просто какие то ваши фантазии. Мало того, вы путаете понятия объекта и ссылки на объект. Всё, что вы написали, не имеет отношения к реальности, птому сам ваш вопрос непонятнен. Попробуйте переформулировать или конретизировать вопрос, чтобы можно было дать четкий ответ, а не переписывать сюда документацию.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Если говорить очень упрощенно (то есть это не всегда верно, но для понимания сойдет), то в C# есть 2 области памяти: стек и куча.

### Куча

Куча служит для хранения объектов. Например, экземпляров классов. Эта куча доступна для любого потока вашей программы. Вопрос только в том, знает ли поток что из жтой кучи взять. Напирмер, если у вас в куче хранится объект и поток А имеет ссылку на него, то есть он знает, то по такуому то адресу в куче лежит экземпляр такого то класса - то он может этот экземпляр класса считать и вызвать его методы/свойства/поля и тд. Но если поток Б не имеет ссылки на экземпляр и ему неоткуда её взять, то он так и не узнает, что там в куче. Простой пример.

```
void MyFunction()
{
    var myObject = new MyClass();
}
```

В коде выше `myObject` - это переменная, которая хранит адрес объекта, то есть адрес экземпляра класса `MyClass`. Этот объект живет, пока выполняется функция. Адрес этого объекта никуда не передается. Таким образом, об этом объекте знает только тот поток, который в данный момент выполняет эту функцию, только он имеет к нему доступ. Этот код выше обычно получается потокобезопасным (если сам `MyClass` внутри себя не содержит ничего, что ломает его потокобезопасность, например обращение к статическим полям).

Теперь давайте усложним задачу и добавим поле

```
private MyClass myField = new MyClass();
void MyFunction()
{
    var myObject = myField;
}
```

И мы видим, что объект сам, то есть экземпляр `MyClass` также будет лежать в куче, но его область видимости не ограничена функцией. Любой из потоков может получить доступ к объекту через поле класса. Раз любой поток может это сделать, то значит любой поток может работать с этим объектом, вызывать методы, иенять состояние и тд. Код выше не является потокобезопасным.

Таким образом, когда мы говорим о разделяемом доступе, можно сказать, что не важно как был создан объект, н если он лежит в куче и у потока есть ссылка на него, то поток может его считать и с ним работать.

### Стек

Чтобы говорить о многопоточности и стеке, надо понимать, что такое стек. Стек - это, грубо говоря, временное хранилище состояний функций. Например, поглядит следующий код:

```
void MyFunction1()
{
    int i1 = 10;
    MyFunction2();
    i1 = 15;
}

void MyFunction2()
{
    int i2 = 10;
}
```

Допустим, мы вызываем функцию `MyFunction1()`, она начинает выполняться, и потом доходит до вызова `MyFunction2();` - что при этом происходит? Как происходит вызов одной функции из другой?

Вот примерный псевлоалгоритм:

- вызов функции `MyFunction1()`
- поместить в стек `int i1`
- записать в `i1` значение 10

  - вызов функции `MyFunction2();`
  - поместить в стек `int i2`
  - записать в `i2` значение 10
  - удалить из стека переменную `i2`
  - конец функции `MyFunction2();`
- записать в `i1` значение 15
- удалить из стека переменную `i1`
- конец функции `MyFunction1();`

Отсюда можно сделать несколько выводов:

1. Стек содержит в себе состояние переменных функции.
2. Стек растет при увеличении глубины вызовов методов.
3. Стек - он отдельный для каждого потока. У каждого потока свой стек.

И вот тут в игру вступают отличия значимых и ссылочных типов. Поглядим на этот пример

```
private MyClass myField = new MyClass();
void MyFunction()
{
    var myObject = myField;
}
```

Здесь переменная `myObject` представляет собой адрес в памяти в куче. Это не сам объект - это инструкция, где его искать. Значение это переменной (то есть адрес объекта) будет храниться в стеке, но сам объект - в куче. Таким образом, другие потоки не смогут изменить значение переменной `myObject`, но они могут изменить объект, который ледит по адресу, куда указывает `myObject`.

А вот в этом примере

```
private int myField = 10;
void MyFunction()
{
    var myInt = myField;
}
```

Вот тут `var myInt = myField;` происходит копирование значения `myField` в переменую `myInt` и значение переменной `myInt` будет лежать в стеке. То есть после присваивания уже никто, кроме текущего потока, не сможет изменить значение `myInt`, так как оно полностью лежит в стеке и не имеет ничего общего с кучей.

### Вопросы

> И для чего разделяемые поля часто помечают модификатором static?

Это утверждение не соотвенствует действительности.

> почему поток может застрять внутри лока функции pop, если здесь Monitor.Enter и Exit, в конструкции Wait не используется

`lock` - это и [есть](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement) `Monitor.Enter` + `Monitor.Exit` + `try-finally`.

Comment: Нормально вы постарались с ответом!

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался, но в ответе на последний вопрос не допонял, каким образом, поток может зависать в lock, если Monitor.Wait как я понимаю его задерживает до Pulse, а при Enter и Exit, он не должен ничего ожидать.

Comment: @faketogosamogo не должен ожидать только для первого входа, если до того как после первого входа еще не было выхода, еще один поток попытается в этот же монитор войти, монитор его подвесит в ожидании выхода из секции первого потока, который первым успел захватить `lock`. А зависание намертво называется дедлок (deadlock). И причина этому не монитор, а попытка выполнения кода на заблокированном этим монитором потоке. Поток не может одновременно "висеть" на мониторе и выполнять где-то другой код. Тема популярная, легко гуглится.

Answer (score 2):

> что именно нужно локать в методе, а что нет

Если говорить об общем случае, то использовать блокировку нужно тогда, когда нужно обеспечить целостность разделяемого ресурса (т.е. обеспечить сохранение инвариантов, например гарантировать, что операция `increment` всегда увеличивает счетчик ровно на 1) при операциях, которые не являются атомарными без явной блокировки.
Второе использование это безопасная публикация изменений, т.е. чтобы гарантировать, что другие потоки увидят изменения в состоянии сделанные потоком.

Под разделяемым ресурсом тут понимается объект, к которому есть доступ из разных потоков.

Отсюда следует, что если к объекту возможен доступ только из одного потока, то нет смысла использовать блокировки при работе с ним. Это вы скорее всего имеете ввиду (но используете не совсем точные формулировки) тут:

> объекты создаваемые в методе не являются общими между потоками и не могут пересечься

Правильно будет сказать "если объект создается потоком, но потом ссыкла на объект не присваивается в статические поля или в поля объектов доступных другим потокам а также созданный объект не использует внутри себя другие объекты доступные из других потоков".

Также из этого следует, что неизменямый (immutable) объект можно безопасно использовать из разных потоков без блокировок (т.к. в нем нет модифицирующих операций).

> для чего разделяемые поля часто помечают модификатором static

Скорее всего вы тут путаете причину и следствие. Статические поля доступны всем потокам и поэтому они являются разделяемыми.

Comment: Спасибо, понял.