# объясните рекурсию на рабоче-крестьянском языке

Tags: java

имеем данный код

```
    public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        up_and_down(1);
    }

    public static void up_and_down(int i) {
        System.out.println("уровень вверх " + i);
        if (i < 3)
            up_and_down(i + 1);


            System.out.println("уровень вниз " + i);

    }
}
```

и вывод

```
уровень вверх 1
уровень вверх 2
уровень вверх 3
уровень вниз 3
уровень вниз 2
уровень вниз 1
```

статьи читал, там эти факториалы, еще больше запутался.

помогите понять данное явление...
я это понимаю как вложенный if, сначала прокрутились по внутреннему циклу, затем вышли во внешний.
Но не могу понять почему идёт обратный отсчёт?????

Comment: Никакого "цикла" тут нет.

Comment: Рекурсия - когда функция вызывает сама себя.
`if` никакого отношения к понятию рекурсия не имеет.
Просто часто бесконечная рекурсия не нужна, и тогда нужно проверить какое-либо условия для выхода из рекурсии. Это можно выполнить с помощь привычного `if`

Comment: делаем 3 итерации 1=>2=>3    и снова вызываем метод, а почему отсчёт идёт в обратную сторону 3=>2=>1 ???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы вызываете функцию `up_and_down` и у вас сразу печатается `1`, т.к. `1 < 3`, то вы вызываете эту же функцию. И теперь функция, где `i = 1` будет ждать пока вызов `up_and_down(i + 1)` выполнится.

В функции, где `i = 2` происходит аналогичное, мы сначала печатаем `2` в консоль и т.к. `2 < 3`, то вызываем функцию `up_and_down(3)`. И теперь функция `up_and_down(1)` ждет, выполнение `up_and_down(2)`, а она ожидает `up_and_down(3)`.

На данный момент мы имеем в консоли 3 строчки `уровень вверх 1` и до 3-х.

Т.к. 3 не меньше 3, мы на этот раз не вызываем рекурсивно еще одну функцию, а печатаем `уровень вниз 3` в консоль. И на этом функция `up_and_down(3)` закончила свою работу и мы обратно переходим в `up_and_down(2)`.

В ней мы печатаем `уровень вниз 2` и функция завершает свою работу и теперь опять переходим в `up_and_down(1)` и печатаем в консоль `уровень вниз 1`. И выходим!

Попробуйте просто пройтись дебаггером по своему примеру.

Небольшой рисунок):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: это типа - зарядили 3 патрона в обойму, а для разрядки можем достать только 3й, потом 2й и затем 3й.??

Comment: Да, сначала 3 потом 2 и только потом не 3-й а 1-й) Вы сейчас рассказали структуру [стека](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Стек) - первый входит, последний выходит. Именно так это и работает с рекурсивными функциями.

Comment: благодарю, а то читал на примере факториалов и чисел Фибоначчи, вообще ничего не понял.

Comment: @стасевич вам возможно будет полезно почитать [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1207996/179763).

Comment: @ tym32167 благодарю, надо будет ещё раз завтра на свежую голову перечитать.