# C# хранение данных в стеке и куче

Tags: c#, .net

Начал изучать устройство памяти в .net и уже понял что в стеке хранятся параметры методов и его локальные переменные в виде значение если эти переменные value-типа и в виде ссылки на место в куче, если объект - reference типа, но что если есть класс А, внутри которого есть поле с другим классом В, где в таком случае будет хранится ссылка на класс В?? В куче там же где и все остальные поля класса А, или в стеке??

```
class B
{
    private int i = 0;
}

class A
{
    private int k = 0;
    private B _b = new B();
}
void Execute()
{
    var a = new A();
    //На данном этапе, ССЫЛКА на экземпляр класса B (поле _b) будет лежать в стеке или в куче?
}
```

Comment: Поле является частью класса и будет храниться там же, где сам класс, то есть в куче,

Comment: @tym32167 если класс создаётся и уничтожается в пределах одной области видимости и во время выполнения этой области не покидает её (никуда не передаётся, в т.ч во время выполнения конструктора) - разве он должен помещаться в кучу? В данном случае если мы создали экземпляры класса А и класса B и тут-же уничтожили будут ли они в куче?

Comment: @Blackmeser если класс создан и ссылка на него существует только в локальной переменной метода (например), то класс сам будет в куче, переменная - в стеке.

Comment: @Blackmeser не совсем ответ, но может что то прояснить https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1207996/179763

Comment: Сам объект класса В будет храниться в куче, а указатель на него будет храниться в стэке

Comment: @RomanIeromenko `есть класс А, внутри которого есть поле с другим классом В`

Comment: Обновил пост выше, дабы точнее показать что имелось ввиду.

Comment: в вашем примере, переменная `a` хранится в стеке, но значение этой переменной - это ссылка на кучу, где хранится экземпляр класса A и все его поля.

Comment: По теории ссылка на 'a' - в стеке, 'i','k','_b' - в куче. НО ИМХО, сдаётся мне что если откомпилить релизом и смотреть ассемблерный код функции Execute после чудесных действий оптимизатора - всё будет в стеке. Т.к. по факту полезных данных в конкретном случае - всего 8 байт, которые никуда не передаются. Но это только предположение. Более того пример сильно ограничен и будь я оптимизатором - я бы выбросил всё целиком.

Comment: В стек помещается то, что требуется, чтобы выполнить заданный код (как бы это банально не звучало). Вы написали `var a = new A()` - в стек поместили ссылку на экземпляр `A` (точнее создали и записали в переменную локальную, но это детали). Сами данные (экземпляр) были созданы в куче и хранятся там, потому что в стеке им делать нечего. А если например сделать все поля не приватным, а публичными, и написать, например, `var i = a._b.i`. Вот тогда сначала из `a` в стек поместят значение поля `_b` (т.е. тоже ссылку), а потом из `B` в стек положат значение `i`.

Comment: Правда с `var i = a._b.i` тоже не всё так просто. В стек ссылка на `B` положится, но в стеке не останется. Потому что ссылка задействуется для получения значения `i`. В общем, если хочешь разобраться, то можно угореть по `System.Reflection.Emit`, но это хардкорная тема. Поизучай тамошние opcodes и может пару методов написать. С большой вероятностью ты сразу поймёшь, что это за стек, нафига он и как вообще вся эта фигня работает...

Comment: В стеке, но есть нюанс. Например в данном конкретном примере ссылка не попадет ни в стек, не в кучу, а будет жить в регистре процессора. Но я думаю, что данный факт можно приравнять к стеку.

Comment: Я просто в общем случае сказал

Comment: Опять хороший вопрос закрыли... :( Имхо, вопрос-дубликат не совсем про то. / Где размещать экземпляры класса - в куче или на стеке - это дело рантайма и не относится напрямую к языку. / В некоторых реализациях JVM (Java Virtual Machine) осуществляется escape analysis и объект может быть создан на стеке. В CLR долгое время такого анализа не было, но в .NET Core уже есть экспериментальная поддержка escape analysis.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, а в чем принципиальное отличие от дубликата?

Comment: @Grundy - тогда ещё не было реализации escape analysis. Сейчас уже есть. То есть объект класса может храниться на стеке. / Я не ожидал, что один мой голос переоткроет вопрос.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, золотой знак потому что :-) Как на счет того, чтобы добавить ответ тут, либо закрыть как дубликат и добавить ответ в том вопросе?

Comment: Если говорить про стек, кучу, ссылку, то я бы привел пример про `C/C++`, где можно нормально описать то чем является указатель, нежели ссылка на объект в `С#`. И почему именно указатель указывает на объект, а не указатель является объектом, на который он указывает, тогда будет немного понятнее.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, закрыл опять, допиши пожалуйста ответ с новой информацией.